# Cannot resolve method 'getCurrentLocation' in 'FusedLocationProviderClient'

Tags: android, android-fusedlocation, fusedlocationproviderclient

I am trying to use `FusedLocationProviderClient.getCurrentLocation()`.

It's supposed to be available according to the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#getCurrentLocation(int,%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.CancellationToken)).

But in Android Studio, I am getting the error

> Cannot resolve method 'getCurrentLocation' in 'FusedLocationProviderClient'

I know the recommended approach is to implement `requestLocationUpdates()`, but that's not what I am after here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to update to at least version 17.1.0 of the Google Play Location Services api. Include this line in your `build.gradle` (app):

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0"
```

Comment: omg this worked! how did you even know? i couldnt find it in the documentation.

Comment: See release notes for September 23, 2020: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

Comment: thanks Mario! Btw, classic Googlers. If I had a cent for each time their doc is incomplete, not up to date, or missing key informations, I would be a millionare lol. I swear 90% times their own code examples from docs do not work and I have to look elsewhere why it does not work...Almost every single time.

Comment: It works before I used ``` implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0' ```